# How to visulaize linear model prediction in ggplot along with confidence interval?

Tags: r, ggplot2, stat

Suppose I'm using my_df to fit a linear model. After getting the estimates I want to see how well model1 can predict n case of another dataset. I'm not sure if the following is the right way to visualize that and how I can add confidence interval bonds based on model1 estimates.

```
#Make up a dataframe and perform a linear model
res <- c(2,3.1,4.5,5.1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,11.8,12.3) 
predictor1 <- c(4.2, 5.3, 5.68,6.5, 7.77,8.5,9.5, 10.18,11.64,12.15,14.19) 
predictor2 <- c(3.1, 5.2, 6.3,7.1, 9.7,11.5,12.99, 14.5 ,15.5,16.41,17.6)
my_df <- data.frame(res, predictor1, predictor2)

 model1<- lm(res~predictor1+predictor2,data = my_df)
#____Another dataset
response<- c(12.5,13.5,14.65,16.1,16.5,17.22,18.54,21.31,23.61,25.58,26.43) 
x1<- c(14.21, 15.13, 16.25,16.5, 17.37,18.51,19.35, 22.18,23.64,25.12,26.19) 
x2<- c(13.11, 15.22, 16.23,17.41, 18.72,21.5,22.99, 24.35 ,25.15,26.21,28.5)
 observeddata <- data.frame(y, x1, x2)
 #I need to check how model1 predicts the response based on the two new predictors(x1&x2) using the estimates of model1

observeddata$prediction<- predict(model1, newdata = observeddata)

#is this a good way to visulize how good or bad model1 works in case of  second dataset?
 ggplot(data=observeddata, aes(x=prediction,y=response))+ geom_point() 
#How can I add confidence interval in this plot? 
#based on what @alistaire suggested I get something like this in case of my  dataset, am I doing it right?!!!
```

[image: Noisy Ribbon]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you flip your axes, you can use `geom_ribbon`. You can get the necessary numbers from `predict` if you tell it you want a confidence interval, too:

```r
library(ggplot2)

my_df <- data.frame(
    res = c(2,3.1,4.5,5.1,6.5,7.1,8.5,9.11,10.1,11.8,12.3), 
    predictor1 = c(4.2, 5.3, 5.68,6.5, 7.77,8.5,9.5, 10.18,11.64,12.15,14.19), 
    predictor2 = c(3.1, 5.2, 6.3,7.1, 9.7,11.5,12.99, 14.5 ,15.5,16.41,17.6))

model1<- lm(res ~ predictor1 + predictor2, data = my_df)

#____Another dataset
observeddata <- data.frame(
    response = c(12.5,13.5,14.65,16.1,16.5,17.22,18.54,21.31,23.61,25.58,26.43), 
    predictor1 = c(14.21, 15.13, 16.25,16.5, 17.37,18.51,19.35, 22.18,23.64,25.12,26.19), 
    predictor2 = c(13.11, 15.22, 16.23,17.41, 18.72,21.5,22.99, 24.35 ,25.15,26.21,28.5))

# adds 3 columns (fit, lwr, upr), so use `cbind` instead of just adding a column
observeddata <- cbind(observeddata, 
                      predict(model1, newdata = observeddata, interval = 'confidence'))

                            # add extra aesthetics for geom_ribbon
ggplot(data = observeddata, aes(x = response, y = fit, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_ribbon(alpha = .3)    # set opacity so points are visible
```

If you really want your axes as they were, add `coord_flip`.

[image]

Comment: And if most of your data occur outside of the dark zone, you could infer that the model doesn't predict well, right? Is it the typical way of depicting the prediction performance of a model?

Comment: Not really. To tell if it's a good model, you ultimately care about test error. Since you're plotting actual vs. predicted, you want that graph to line up along the line y = x. R^2 and p-values are helpful in pointing you in the right direction, as are residual plots.

Comment: Thanks @alistaire for your help. I always considered a well-performing model to have a scatterplot of fit Vs. observed very close to 1:1 line.  Obviously, that is not the proper way for evaluating prediction power a model, right?

Comment: In a way it is, because that means your residuals are small. It's frequently useful to have a number to tell you how close it is, though, i.e. RMSE. "How do I know if my model is good" is a big question, though, maybe better suited to [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).